# Why are null measuring methods considered to be very precise?

Tags: measurement, current-measurement, voltage-measurement, wheatstone-bridge

I heard a professor saying "it's a null method, so it is very precise".

He was talking about the force balance pressure measuring method.

I think in this category of methods one can include the Wheatstone bridge (with balanced arms) or other methods where a galvanometer is used.

But why is this more accurate than other methods? My intuition tells me that the accuracy of a non-zero reading can be "more affected" by many factors..., but i'm not sure...

Comment: Note that he said "precise", not "accurate". Null methods work by creating a reference signal that's equal to the signal being measured. It's easy to make the reference signal match the unknown *precisely*, but the absolute *accuracy* of the measurement (relative to accepted standards) depends on how accurate/stable your reference generator is and/or your ability to measure its output accurately. The distinction is subtle, but important.

Answer (score 5):

There are two key benefits of null-balance measuring methods.

The first is that the quantity being measured is not affected in any way by the measurement when the system is in balance; i.e., there are no "loading" effects.

The second is that since the measurement is always made at the same point on the indicating device, any nonlinearities in the indicating device itself do not affect the measurement at all. The only requirement is that the indicating device must have good "repeatability", which means that it always comes back to the same point for the same quantity being measured, regardless of its previous history.

Answer (score 3):

In general, you can achieve a null much more easily and more precisely than if you were to attempt to achieve a peak value. Achieving a precise peak means, for example, being able to tell the difference between 10.000 units and 10.001 units, while achieving a precise null means being to tell the difference between 0.000 units and 0.001 units. Errors affect the former measurement more than the latter measurement.

Answer (score 2):

In most cases the measuring instrument influences the measured system which results in an error. Sometimes it's not possible to calculate that error and correct the result.

In the example of the wheatstone bridge it's the goal to have no current through the instrument. When this current is zero, the electrical properties of the instrument have no influence on the circuit. You can use the most sensitive instrument available and ignore the internal resistance, it doesn't matter.

As the example from your professor shows, it seems that this principle can be transfered to non electric measurements.